# An Ambiguous Text from the Oracle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, story

**Oscar**: Hey bra, let's go to the pub and tie one on.

**Peter**: Naw bra, don't you know Mercury's in retrograde?

**Oscar**: Hmm, let's consult the Oracle.

Oscar texted the Oracle and the Oracle immediately replied:

[image: iMessage app showing messages. See bottom of post for transcription]

**Peter**: See, I told you we shouldn't go.

**Oscar**: What're you talking about? Let's party!

*What was the Oracle's response?*

---

<sub>Text version of Oscar's text to the Oracle:</sub>

> Yo Oracle, what awaits us if we go out?

<sub>Text version of the Oracle's response:</sub>

> Threshold of life
> ♈️
>
> DC Comics Lords of _____
> ♉️
>
> One playing Among Us
> ♊️
>
> Handle a Foursquare friend request
> ♎️
>
> Hacker hat color
> ♏️
>
> ♈️♉️♉️♊️➕♎️♏️♉️♉️♊️

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems that

> Oscar the optimist and Peter the pessimist see the same things differently...

*Threshold of life*

> Oscar: **B**IRTH
>  Peter: **D**EATH

*DC Comics Lords of _____*

> Oscar: ORD**E**R
>  Peter: CHA**O**S

*One playing Among Us*

> Oscar: C**R**EWMATE
>  Peter: I**M**POSTOR

*Handle a friend request*

> Oscar: A**C**CEPT
>  Peter: I**G**NORE

*Hacker hat color*

> Oscar: W**H**ITE
>  Peter: B**L**ACK

Taking the corresponding letters from the answers can spell the responses

> Oscar: **BEER + CHEER**
>  Peter: **DOOM + GLOOM**

Comment: nice job. Made a slight edit, feel free to roll it back.